# Why directly imported functions in GHC differ so much with functions I write with the source code copied from GHC Libraries

Tags: debugging, haskell, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, ghc-api

```
module Has (r,p,s) where

import Prelude ((==),Bool(..),otherwise,(||),Eq)
import qualified Data.List as L

filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter _pred []    = []
filter pred (x:xs)
  | pred x         = x : filter pred xs
  | otherwise      = filter pred xs
```

problem1: This `filter` is copied from `GHC`'s library, but why it consumes a growing number of memory *in contrast with* the directly imported `filter`, which consumes a constant number of memory.

```
elem :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem _ []       = False
elem x (y:ys)   = x==y || elem x ys
```

problem2: This `filter` is copied from `GHC`'s library, but why it consumes a growing number of memory *like* the directly used `elem`, which *also* consumes a growing number of memory *in contrast with* the directly imported `filter`.

```
r = L.filter (==1000000000000) [0..]
p = filter (==1000000000000) [0..]
s = 1000000000000 `elem` [0..]
```

GHC version:7.4.2          OS:Ubuntu 12.10        Compiled with -O2 to optimize

As the above `filter` and `elem` 's definitions imply both `p = filter (==1000000000000) [0..]` and `` s = 1000000000000 `elem` [0..] `` 's `[0..]` should be garbage collected gradually. But both `p` and `s` consumes a growing number of memory. And `r` which is defined with the directly imported `filter` consumes a constant number of memory.

My question is why directly imported functions in GHC differ so much with functions I write with the source code copied from GHC Libraries. I wonded if there is something wrong with GHC?

I has a further question: The above code is abstracted from a project I writed, and the project also faces the problem of "consumes a growing number of memory, which should be garbage collected in theory". So I want to know that is there a way to find which variable takes up so much memory in GHC.

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: GHC version, OS? I cannot reproduce the memory growth implementing `elem` just like that.

Comment: Copied from the GHC library? There's actually a lot more in there than just these definitions, for instance [`{-# RULES "filter" [~1] forall p xs.  filter p xs = build (\c n -> foldr (filterFB c p) n xs) #-}`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#filter), which means the definition you quoted normally won't be used. – That said, I also can't reproduce your memory consumpion issues. What optimisation flags do you use?

Comment: I think he means the definitions in the standard Prelude. Can't reproduce the problem either, by the way.

Comment: Note that the *exact* way in which you have simplified your real code can make a big difference! E.g. is the 'big list' `[0..]` computed anew for `r`,`p`, and `s`; or is it somehow shared (as a top-level definition or as an argument to a function?) I guess we're going to have to see a bit more of your code...

Comment: Also, how do you compile your code? `-O`? Or are you running it in the interpreter?

Comment: Joachim Breitner : Yes, I compiled it with -O2

Comment: You compiled it with `-O2`, but you ran it in ghci when you got the increasing memory consumption, didn't you?

Comment: Joachim Breitner: Yes, I tried to run it in Shell, and it only used about 800k ram. That's amazing. I never realized it. Could you explain that to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the memory consumption in ghci is not the code of `filter` or `elem`. (Although the rewrite rule for `filter` in `GHC.List` makes it a little better usually.)

Let's look at (part of) the core ghc-7.4.2 produced with `-O2` (`-ddump-simpl`). First for `r`, using `GHC.List.filter`:

```
Has.r1
  :: GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
     -> [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer] -> [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]
[GblId,
 Arity=2,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=2, Value=True,
         ConLike=True, Cheap=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=IF_ARGS [0 0] 60 30}]
Has.r1 =
  \ (x_awu :: GHC.Integer.Type.Integer)
    (r2_awv :: [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]) ->
    case GHC.Integer.Type.eqInteger x_awu Has.p5 of _ {
      GHC.Types.False -> r2_awv;
      GHC.Types.True ->
        GHC.Types.: @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer x_awu r2_awv
    }

Has.r :: [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]
[GblId,
 Str=DmdType,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=0, Value=False,
         ConLike=False, Cheap=False, Expandable=False,
         Guidance=IF_ARGS [] 40 0}]
Has.r =
  GHC.Enum.enumDeltaIntegerFB
    @ [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer] Has.r1 Has.p3 Has.p2
```

`Has.p3` is `0 :: Integer`, and `Has.p2` is `1 :: Integer`. The rewrite rules (for `filter` and `enumDeltaInteger`) turned it into (with shorter names)

```
r = go fun 0 1
  where
    go foo x d = x `seq` (x `foo` (go foo (x+d) d))

fun n list
    | n == 1000000000000 = n : list
    | otherwise          = list
```

which could probably be a bit more efficient if `fun` was inlined, but the point is that the list to be `filter`ed doesn't exist as such, it was fused away.

For `p` on the other hand, without the rewrite rule(s), we get

```
Has.p1 :: [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]
[GblId,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=0, Value=False,
         ConLike=False, Cheap=False, Expandable=False,
         Guidance=IF_ARGS [] 30 0}]
Has.p1 = GHC.Enum.enumDeltaInteger Has.p3 Has.p2

Has.p :: [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]
[GblId,
 Str=DmdType,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=0, Value=False,
         ConLike=False, Cheap=False, Expandable=False,
         Guidance=IF_ARGS [] 30 0}]
Has.p = Has.filter @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer Has.p4 Has.p1
```

a top-level CAF for the list `[0 .. ]` (`Has.p1`), and `Has.filter` applied to `(== 1000000000000)` and the list.

So this one does create the actual list to be filtered - thus it's somewhat less efficient.

But normally (running a compiled binary), that's no problem in terms of memory consumption, since the list is garbage collected as it is consumed. However, for reasons that are beyond me, ghci does keep the list `[0 .. ]` around when evaluating `p` or `s` (but that has its own copy of `[0 .. ]`, so it's not unwanted sharing here), as can be gleaned from the `-hT` heap profile (evaluating `s`, so there's only one possible source for the list cells. ghci invoked with `+RTS -M300M -hT -RTS`, so shortly after the memory usage reached 300M, ghci terminated):

[image]

So the cause of the memory consumption in ghci is the hardcoding of the list to be filtered. If you use `Has.filter` with a list supplied at the prompt, the memory usage is constant as expected.

I'm not sure whether ghci retaining the list `[0 .. ]` is a bug or intended behaviour.